# System.Web.Globalization namespace introduced with .NET 4.6.2 conflicts at runtime with System.Globalization

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, .net-4.6.2

After installing the Windows 10 Anniversary Update over the weekend, which includes .NET Framework 4.6.2, some code stopped working. I've gone back to a version of 1 week ago to make sure it's not related to our code.

At runtime, an error is thrown:

> error BC30561: 'Globalization' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'System.Web, System'.

Stack trace:

```
System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): C:\path\to\project\MasterPages\SiteMaster.master(71): error BC30561: 'Globalization' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'System.Web, System'.
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.PostProcessFoundBuildResult(BuildResult result, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetBuildResultFromCacheInternal(String cacheKey, Boolean keyFromVPP, VirtualPath virtualPath, Int64 hashCode, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.GetReferencedType(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean allowNoCompile)
   at System.Web.UI.PageParser.ProcessMainDirectiveAttribute(String deviceName, String name, String value, IDictionary parseData)
   at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessMainDirective(IDictionary mainDirective)
```

This is the offending line:

```
$.SetLanguage("<%= Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName %>");
```

Replacing `Globalization` with `System.Globalization` fixes the problem, but Visual Studio suggests that the "name can be simplified", indicating `System` is not necessary.

When setting a breakpoint at the offending line, I can get the same error via the Immediate Window:

```
Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture
error BC30560: 'CultureInfo' is ambiguous in the namespace 'System.Globalization'.
```

If I understand correctly, there is both `System.Globalization` and `System.Web.Globalization`. According to [the API diff](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net462/dotnet462-api-changes.md), a new namespace was introduced, which seems to be causing this issue.

> ```
> +namespace System.Web.Globalization {
> +    public interface IStringLocalizerProvider {
> +        string GetLocalizedString(CultureInfo culture, string name, params object[] arguments);
> +    }
> +    public sealed class ResourceFileStringLocalizerProvider : IStringLocalizerProvider {
> +        public const string ResourceFileName = "DataAnnotation.Localization";
> +        public ResourceFileStringLocalizerProvider();
> +        public string GetLocalizedString(CultureInfo culture, string name, params object[] arguments);
> +    }
> +    public static class StringLocalizerProviders {
> +        public static IStringLocalizerProvider DataAnnotationStringLocalizerProvider { get; set; }
> +    }
> +}
> ```

Why does this error only appear at runtime? How can I make it fail at compile time?

Comment: Seems the offending line is inline code in aspx page which is compiled during the first request. You can use aspnet_compiler.exe to precompile your web app and you should see the error.

Comment: Same issue I am getting. The code was working fine but after reinstalling VS and all other thing, it started giving same error. but I got after instllation of Framework 4.5.2. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @par The solution is to fully qualify the type and ignore Visual Studio when it says the name can be simplified. I assume it's also not a problem if your project targets 4.6.2 but I haven't tried yet.

Comment: @Stijn, thanks. My project targets 4.5.1

Comment: Had the same problem with a web site(.net 4.0)

Answer (score 8):

Bug Crusher's answer is correct.  To address Stijn's comment to the answer, just search your project for "Globalization." and remove every instance of it. I wouldn't use Find + Replace to do this as that may have unintended side effects.

Then make sure each file you edited has the correct import or using statement on top.

VB-
`Imports System.Globalization`

C#-
`using System.Globalization;`

That's the fix VS would've proposed.

Answer (score 3):

We removed the "Globalization." and let Visual Studio propose a fix. We chose "Import System.Globalization" which it added to the file for us.

This got rid of the error and the site works OK.

Comment: I can't get VS to propose me a fix, there are no Quick Actions available.